# Is there a way to change object memory address?

Tags: java

I am need to write an obfuscation mechanism and think that the cracker can just read desired address in memory and access my object. All that I have so far come up with for the role of protection against this is the frequent "shuffling" of addresses in the heap. As far as I know, in garbage collection, the collector can do this.

My question is: is it possible in Java 8 to implement such a "shuffle" or at least change the address of a particular object, if so, how?

Comment: How would that help? A cracker could simply run your application in a debugger, so no matter how quickly you change the address, they'll just pause the application and look through it at their leisure.

Comment: this application is a plug-in for an other standalone application and isn't executable. He cannot do this.

Comment: They could run the other application in a debugger then.

Comment: … or use/inject something like [Frida](https://frida.re/)

Comment: @ifxandy Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").

Answer (score 3):

> I am need to write an obfuscation mechanism and think that the cracker can just read desired address in memory and access my object.

You are probably trying to solve a problem that doesn't really exist.  For a non-trivial Java program, it is extremely unlikely that a specific object will have the same memory address across multiple runs of your application.  So checking the content of fixed memory addresses to find objects would not offer any "leverage" for the hacker.  And ... it follows that *moving* objects won't improve security.

Having said that, the Java language and the Java Virtual Machine provide no way to move objects in memory.  The closest you will get is to create a new object ... which will have a different address to the old one ... copy its state, and then update any variables containing references to it.

---

Finally ...

If the hackers (or customers who you don't trust) control the hardware or operating system on which your application is running, then there is nothing you can do to physically prevent them from hacking your code ... if they have enough time, skill and motivation.

Anything you can conceivably do can be subverted.  Trying to come up with clever ways to make hacking more difficult is ultimately futile.

Answer (score 1):

Java itself does not provide you with any API to manipulate the address of an object instance on the heap.

The JVM as such knows how to manipulate object addresses, and there are several ways to access this features, but not from the Java programming language, nor from any other JVM language I am aware of.

Comment: Can i access this features using, for example, C++? Maybe I need memory hacking for this purposes?

Comment: Yes, as this is how Garbage Collectors are implemented. Basically, you have to write your own Garbage Collector, as you want to tamper the addresses of objects and that might collide with the real GCs …